# Find the unit vector given the directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the equation
$$ f(x)=x^2 -xy+y^2-y $$

I am asked to find the unit vector $\hat n$, such that $D_{\hat n} f(1,-1)$ equals to 4.

So far, finding the $\nabla f$ at $(1,-1)$ gives the result of $(3,-4)$.

As $|\hat n| =1,$ $$|\nabla f| cos{\theta}=4$$
$$cos{\theta} =0.8$$
$$\hat n = (cos{\theta},sin{\theta})= (\frac45, \frac 35)$$
$$\nabla f \cdot \hat n = (3,-4)\cdot(\frac45, \frac 35)=0\not=4 $$

As far as I know, solving for the dot product $\nabla f \cdot \hat n =4 $ is also another way.
However, solving for $(a,b)$ with $ (3,-4)\cdot(a,b)=4$ doesn't seem to give me my answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We need to find the unknown $\hat n=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ by

$$(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)\cdot (3,-4)=3\cos\theta-4\sin \theta=4$$

Comment: I was able to get the unit vectors from this method. One question though, how/why is the angle theta here different than the one I mentioned above?

Comment: @Jerry The angle theta is unknown we need to find that by the given condition, You should. What is the solution you have found? It should be useful if you could add that to your question. Bye

Answer (score 0):

If $\hat n=(a,b)$ is a unit vector, you get a system with two equations:

$3a-4b=4$,

$a^2+b^2=1$.

Comment: the solution works, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your first method finds the cosine of the angle correctly, but this angle is measured from $\nabla f$. You computed a vector that makes this angle with the positive $x$-axis instead. If you rotate $\nabla f$ by this angle and normalize to get a unit vector, you’ll find that the derivative in that direction has the correct value. Note that there are two solutions, since there are two values of $\theta$ for which $\cos\theta = 4/5$.

Alternatively, one solution is obviously $(0,-1)$. The other solution is its reflection in $\nabla f$.